# JavaFX spinner - не работают стрелочки

Tags: javafx

Добавил Spinner в fxml файл, прописал в Controller, могу использовать textfield, при нажатии на стрелочки ничего не изменяется..

```
@FXML private Spinner<Integer> countSpinner = new Spinner<>(0, 100, 0);
```

Comment: Вы переинициализировали объект, который уже создан FXMLLoader`ом( либо наоборот )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вы переинициализировали объект, который уже создан FXMLLoader`ом( либо наоборот )

Вы можете убедиться в этом на минимальном работающем примере (все файлы лежат в пакете sample):

sample.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Spinner?>
<VBox fx:controller="sample.Controller"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" >
    <children>
        <Spinner fx:id="spinner" min="0" max="100" initialValue="0" />
    </children>
</VBox>
```

Controller.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;

public class Controller {
    @FXML Spinner spinner;
}
```

Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```